# VS Code Prettier breaking hash access

Tags: ruby, hash, prettier

I'm trying to access data in a hash like this:

```rb
result&.data['address']['ISO3166-2-lvl4']
```

but when I save the file, Prettier changes it to this:

```rb
result&.data&.[]('ISO3166-2-lvl4')
```

which doesn't work. What is Prettier trying to do here, and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really work if `result` is `nil`:

```rb
>> result = nil
=> nil
>> result&.data[:address][:iso]
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

In general you have to use `&.` for every method that you chain after the first `&.`.

*Prettier* is trying to call [`Hash#[]`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/hash#method-i-5B-5D) method with `&.` operator, which should look like this:

```rb
>> result&.data&.[](:address)&.[](:iso)
=> nil

# it works when you have result and data hash
class Result
  def data = {address: {iso: '123'}}
end
result = Result.new

>> result&.data&.[](:address)&.[](:iso)
=> "123"
```

I think, `&.[]` is an awkward way of doing it, even if *prettier* worked as intended. [`dig`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/hash#method-i-dig) method would be preferable here:

```
>> result&.data&.dig(:address, :iso)
=> "123"
>> result = nil
=> nil
>> result&.data&.dig(:address, :iso)
=> nil
```

---

@engineersmnky
Assuming data hash doesn't actually need safety:

```rb
if result
  result.data[:address][:iso]
end
```

Comment: Leave it to an extension called "Prettier" to make things uglier. Although the actual safe navigation proposal (using `dig`), while correct and functional is also hideous in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
// prettier-ignore
result&.data['address']['ISO3166-2-lvl4']
```

Comment: Ruby uses `#` for commenting out code, but regardless, this feature doesn't seem to be supported for ruby. At least it didn't work for me. Welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: @Arel according to the [Docs](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-ruby#ignoring-code) for the ruby plugin you would need to use `# stree-ignore` instead.